# What causes the JSessionID changing with every request?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I have a JSF 2, EJB 3.1, CDI Application running on a Glassfish 3.1.2. I have noticed that the jsession id allways changes: with every request I send to to server, the retuned page contains links () with an new jsession id, even if the request already contains a jsession id

I do not think that this is normal, but I have no idea what could cause this behavior.

I have configured:

```xml
<session-config>
    <session-properties>
        <property name="enableCookies" value="false" />
        <property name="enableURLRewriting" value="true" />
    </session-properties>
</session-config>
```

but every thing else is default, I do not have any strange configuration or custom jsession generation stuff. -- Does anybody know what can trigger Glassfish/JSF to change the sessionId?

Example:

The application has a menu that is displayed on every page. The jsf page contains this:

`<h:link outcome="/search/search">search</h:link>`

Now I describe the requests and responses. The Requests are simple HTTP GET Requests. The Response allways contains the complete page. No Ajax involved.

1. After some Basic Authentication.
2. The user enters the start page, it contains a menu with a link to the search page, and this link has jsession id (all other links have the same jsessionId) - Details;

   - Request: `http://localhost:8080/myApp/start/start.xhtml`
   - Response content: `<a href="/myApp/search/search.xhtml;jsessionid=8df431e2275052cf2348a4cb793e">search</a>`
3. The user clicks on that link; the returned page contains the the menu again, but now all links have an other sessionjd - Details:

   - Request `http://localhost:8080/myApp/suche/teilnehmer_suche.xhtml;jsessionid=8df431e2275052cf2348a4cb793e`
   - Response content: `<a href="/myApp/search/search.xhtml;jsessionid=8ebeefb6df144a2fee97d87a51e6">...`
4. The user clicks on that link again: the jsession id change again

   - Request `http://localhost:8080/myApp/suche/teilnehmer_suche.xhtml;jsessionid=8df431e2275052cf2348a4cb793e`
   - Response content: `<a href="/myApp/search/search.xhtml;jsessionid=8f4021c2fa628ce3b9c12c545cc4">...`

I can click on that link (and every other link) again and again, but the jsession id changed every time.

---

More strange: after changing the configuration to use cookies instead of urlRewriting I see that this behavior occures even for the resource files:

The client request start.xml without jsession id, the server returns `Set-Cookie    JSESSIONID=a68d3d9260d7ea5fd36a7713eb80; Path=/myapp; HttpOnly` in the response header.

Afterwards the client request the css page with `Cookie JSESSIONID=a68d3d9260d7ea5fd36a7713eb80` and the server send back the css file but the response header contains a new session id: `Set-Cookie   JSESSIONID=a68d550e5093e246b01ba4220cd3; Path=/myapp; HttpOnly`

Comment: Please add info to clarify.  What requests are you making?  Do they include the session identifier either as a cookie or as the URL parameter, and the server is still creating a new session id?  ie, is the server returning a Set-Cookie header, and is the client sending the cookie with subsequent requests?  Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug are both great ways to see what's happening.

Comment: Yes. Please debug the HTTP traffic yourself to see if the cookie flow is as expected. We can't easily beam over to you to check that ourselves.

Comment: @BalusC: sorry for the not so clear statment: I have already debugged the flow and the id allways changed. And I use urlRewriting not cookies. -- I have attached an example to make it more clear.

Comment: @Ryan Boyd: I use urlRewriting, so the session id should be in the url. The request url contains that jsessionId (see example), the request and the response contains no cookie information (as expected).

Comment: is the user authenticated or are these requests being made "anonymous".  if so, you might be seeing behavior by the container to prevent session-fixation exploits.  one of the defenses against that exploit is to rotate the session id/cookie until the user is authenticated, at which point the submitted session id is discarded and a durable one is created for the authenticated session.

Comment: can you put the import you use for the CDI scope you use for your beans

Comment: @him: the problem occured after basic authentication: see step 1

Comment: @hragheb: I do not understand your comment.

Comment: I mean what is the fully class name of the scope you use for your CDI beans. Do you use javax.faces.view.Viewscoped anywhere in your code?

Comment: Yes that application used a view scopes.  But to be honest, this was 3years ago, and the application does not exist anymore.

Comment: @hragheb: I would like to delete this question, because I am not able to support it anymore (it is just to old). But if you still have this problem, I can leave it open.

Comment: I know, I was just curious about the issue since I didn't find an answer. How did you solve the issue if you still remember?